# Nginx open_file_cache

Tags: nginx

I've noticed an interesting issue with open_file_cache. Basically, I have a perl script that updates a page. I've noticed that with open_file_cache on this page will remain the same for the duration of, what I assume to be, the open_file_cache_valid setting. This seems like it shouldn't be happening since the Nginx documentation states the cache only stores this info:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#open_file_cache

Open file descriptors, information with their size and modification time;
Information about the existence of directories;
Error information when searches for a file - no file, do not have rights to read, etc. See also open_file_cache_errors

It seems like the entire page is getting cached in addition to the modify time etc?

Here's the details of what I'm seeing with the following settings:

open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=60s; 
open_file_cache_valid    60s; 
open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
open_file_cache_errors   on;

I run the perl script to update the page, and look at the file with ls:

ls -lh index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 81K Mar 27 12:32 index.html

Nginx doesn't update the page however, and it remains the same for 60 seconds:

Last-Modified: Wed, 27 Mar 2013 16:19:46 GMT

After a minute I refresh and it finally changes. This file has no other cache settings, so is the open_file_cache literally just caching the entire thing? Can I reduce open_file_cache_valid lower or does that defeat the purpose?

Comment: How did you establish that Nginx didn't update the page and it remained the same for 60 seconds? Because it looks like you answered your own question -- as you said, `open_file_cache` caches the modification time.

Comment: because the actual file content remained the same as well. i'm thinking this may be some kind of interaction between the file cache and gzip but i havent tested it yet

Comment: You were expecting the old modification time with the new file content?! That would be a pretty broken design, don't you think? That would cause huge problems for clients.

Comment: Yeah I guess so?? This should be more explicit since the documentation makes it sound like it only keeps the filesystem attributes in a cache, not the actual file.

Comment: I just realized you can do open_file_cache off on location. welp thanks yall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not nginx caching file content, this is your filesystem (Unix?) changing the inode when you update the file.

Since file descriptor information is cached in nginx, inode update is not propagated to it, thus continuing reading the old inode.

On cache invalidation (`open_file_cache`'s `inactive` parameter) or revalidation (`open_file_cache_valid`), file descriptor information gets respectively removed (will be up-to-date on next opening) or updated.

This behavior is specific to each filesystem, this is why [using file descriptor cache on NFS, for one, is advised against](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/478).